# How to distinguish different responses from useFetch custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Basically in my App.js, I need to call useFetch twice to display spinner/data/error for two tables.

How do I go about distinguish which spinner/data/error is for which table? Because in useEffect I'm returning 
**{ data, loading, error }**, and in App.js, I'm getting the value like so **const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(url_order, date)**. But I want **const { data_table1, loading_table1, error_table1 } = useFetch(url_order, date)** instead.

This is my useFetch custom hook

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useFetch(url, date) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const doFetch = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const json = await res.json;
        setData(json.result.result);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(true);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    doFetch();
  }, [date]);

  return { data, loading, error };
}
```

This is my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import useFetch from "./hooks/useFetch";
import OrderTable from "./OrderTable";
import IngredientTable from "./IngredientTable";

const App = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(url_order, date);
  const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(url_ingredient, date);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? (
        <BeatLoader css={override} color={"#36D7B7"} loading={loading} />
      ) : error ? (
        <h3>Failed to fetch data for Order's table</h3>
      ) : (
        <OrderTable data={data} />
      )}

      {loading ? (
        <BeatLoader css={override} color={"#36D7B7"} loading={loading} />
      ) : error ? (
        <h3>Failed to fetch data for Ingredient's table</h3>
      ) : (
        <IngredientTable data={data} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write:

```
const order_table = useFetch(url_order, date);
const ingedient_table = useFetch(url_ingredient, date);
```

Now you can access:

```
order_table.data
order_table.error
order_table.loading

ingedient_table.data
ingedient_table.error
ingedient_table.loading
```

Comment: You are welcome @Young. I have writen another solution below. Take a look at it because I think it is even cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution is to rename the destructured props like this:

```
const { data: order_data, loading: order_loading, error: order_error } = useFetch(url_order, date);
const { data: ingredient_data, loading: ingredient_loading, error: ingredient_error } = useFetch(url_order, date };
```

Now you can access:

```
order_data
order_loading
order_error 
ingredient_data
ingredient_loading
ingredient_error
```

Answer (score 0):

Your useFetch is nothing but a function at the end of the day. You can take advantage of this - Inside your app component, set the initial state with different names by calling the useFetch like so:

```
const [orderData,setOrderData] = useState(useFetch(url_order, date));
const [ingredientData,setIngredientData] = useState(useFetch(url_ingredient, date));
```

Now `orderData` and `ingredientData` are objects with orderData.data, orderData.loading and orderData.error and so on.

Although this is not very clean. Another way is to just have different variable names for each data,loading,error by suffixing them with numbers:

```
 const { data1, loading1, error1 } = useFetch(url_order, date);
  const { data2, loading2, error2 } = useFetch(url_ingredient, date);
```

Comment: I have thought of your first suggestion, but didn't really wanna do it that way (seems too messy). And I have tried your second suggestion, that simply doesn't work. Thank you for suggesting tho!